# Equivalent Forms of Wasserstein Metric

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, metric

Let $F, G$ be two cumulative distribution functions (c.d.f.) over real numbers, the Wasserstein metric is defined as $$d_{p}(F,G)=\inf_{U,V}||U-V||_{p},$$ where the infimum is taken over all joint random variables $(U,V)$ with respective c.d.f. $F$ and $G$. In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06887.pdf) I read, the authors mention that the infimum is attained by the inverse c.d.f. transformation of a random variable $\mathcal{U}$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$: $$d_p(F, G)=||F^{-1}(\mathcal{U})-G^{-1}(\mathcal{U})||_{p}.$$

I surveyed a bit on the internet and many people say it is a well known result in papers, but did not manage to find one proof. Anyone has an idea about how to prove this? Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Proof_of_correctness

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you, but isn't this just saying that $(F^{-1}(\mathcal{U}), G^{-1}(\mathcal{U}))$ is a coupling of $(F, G)$?

Comment: Call it whatever you want. It's a simple, well-known, and highly used (in simulation) technique/result. Maybe that's why no one bothers to prove it.

Comment: These folks https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06923.pdf#page=10&zoom=100,0,0 site this one: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1428011?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents ... but I also am not finding a simple proof quickly.

Comment: And this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05500.pdf clarifies that you only get explicit formulas in two cases (for d=1).

Comment: have you found the proof? I'm also stuck here with why the infimum is achieved by the inverse CDF.

Comment: Page 96-97 of this might be helpful http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~bobko001/preprints/2016_BL_Order.statistics_Revised.version.pdf

Comment: Here is an accessible explanation using copulas: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.03570.pdf